# Checking if username and email already exist within database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to check if the username and email have already been used before. When the user tries to enter a username that has been used before the error message displays. Same with email. However when a user tries to sign-up with a different username and email an error appears saying myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery must be outside rdr close but I can't put it there as it will then not be recognised.

Anybody have a solution to this issue?

```
protected void registerbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string newuser = regusername.Text;
    string newfirst = regfirst.Text;
    string newlast = reglast.Text;
    string newemail = regemail.Text;
    string newpass = regpass.Text;



    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["photoconnection"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


    myConnection.Open();



   string query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=@nuser OR email=@nemail";




   SqlCommand myCommand1= new SqlCommand(query1, myConnection);
   myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nuser", newuser);
   myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nemail", newemail);


   SqlDataReader rdr = myCommand1.ExecuteReader();

    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
       //when in read mode ask for data
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string uname = rdr["username"].ToString();
            string email = rdr["email"].ToString();

            if (regusername.Text == uname)
            {
                samevar.Text = "This Username already exists. Please choose another";

            }

            else if (regemail.Text == email)
            {
                samevar.Text = "This email already has an account associated with it. Please choose another";

            }


      }

      }
    else
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO users (username, firstname, lastname, email, password, userrole) VALUES(@nuser, @nfirst, @nlast, @nemail, @npass, 'registered')";
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nuser", newuser);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@npass", newpass);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nfirst", newfirst);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nemail", newemail);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nlast", newlast);

        regusername.Text = "";
        regpass.Text = "";
        regfirst.Text = "";
        reglast.Text = "";
        regemail.Text = "";

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCommand.Dispose();

    }

    rdr.Close();

    myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myCommand1.Dispose();






    myConnection.Close();

}
```

Comment: What is your error message _exactly_?

Comment: You called ExecuteReader on myCommand1, then you are trying to call ExecuteNonQuery on the exact same command. The data reader is still open with results from the ExecuteReader function. Also, calling ExecuteNonQuery on a select statement is not good. It is meant to be used with update, delete, insert statements

Comment: You are going about this whole thing the wrong way. Using sql server like you do is the same as using a Lamborghini to drive at 10 mph. Use a single stored procedure that will do both the check and the insert and return an output parameter to inform the asp.net if the user already exists or if the insert was successful.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute any commands on a connection which is associated with an open data reader. You have to close the reader or use another connection. Because your reader is used by the open reader exclusively.